# How to add filters depending on another filter selection in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, filter

I have a report with this filters:

1. Division
2. From Date
3. To Date
4. Transporter Or (Transporter - Service)

If the user select Transporter, a list of transporters appear and he can select 1 or many Transporters.
If the user select Transporter - Service, a list of services (in the format Transporter1 - Service1) appear and he can select 1 or many Transporters.

How can I accomplish this in SSRS?

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to cascading parameters. You will have to have a data source a list of values for Transporter and Transporter - Service. It would probably have two fields and look something like this:

```
Type                                  Name
Transporter                           Transporter1
Transporter                           Transporter2
Transporter - Service                 Transporter1 - Service1
Transporter - Service                 Transporter1 - Service2
```

There is a good [tutorial for cascading parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on Technet

Basically, The value of the parameter for type will be used to filter the query for the name parameter.

Comment: The tutorial is very good! But I'm afraid my problem is going further:
1. The forwarder and forwarder-service filters should allow multiple values, so how I manage this in the cascading filters? In the actual report the user must select first (with radio buttons) if he wants to see a forwarder or forwarder-service list.
2. When I was also testing the query (because I need to sometimes apply filters and sometimes not and I used info from a question related here) I found that the parameter didn't work with CSV, any help with this also? Thanks

Comment: For multiple values, check the box that allows multiple values and use in (@type) rather than =@type in the where clause for your query.  I don't understand what you mean with CSV.

Comment: I mean that when you have a multiple values filter and you select more than 1, the filter will return Value1,value2, value3, etc... (that is CSV) and when I use "in (@type)" it doesn't work when I select more than 1 value. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I tried what they said but I still only get records from the 1st value selected, it doesn't matter how many values I select. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Today I tried again to use the "in (@type)" sentence in the query and finally it worked. I only showed the selected values from the filter in a text box and then it started to work. I know it doesn't make sence, but is the only thing I did. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help!